# How to renew certificate with same keystore (same private key) without deploy to my java program again

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, private-key

I got a program which read keystore(.jks) located inside the .jar
My current certificate is expired soon , and I already export the private key from keystore and renewal a new certificate .
I would like to know is that possible keep the keystore(.jks)  unchange and using same private key and same keystore without deploy my program again .
(For client side , I will import the new valid certificate to window certificate trusted store)

The program is using java and keystore create SSLcontext

Thanks

Comment: The new certificate does not magically show up in your keystore. You have to explicitly do it and deploy your program again so that it makes use of the new certificate.

Comment: With a traditional setup it is not possible, but maybe you can give this a try: https://github.com/Hakky54/java-tutorials/tree/main/instant-server-ssl-reloading I demonstrate here how you can change the server certificates without redeploying/restarting it. But for this you probably need to refactor your code

Comment: steffen ullrich , as keystore holds private key and not changed . suppose if i got the matched public key on local trusted certifacte store . it should be work ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the set of commands I used to create the new certificate for the same private key.

1. Extract the private key from the legacy JKS

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore legacykeystore.jks -srcalias mykey -destalias mykey -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeypass 123456

   openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out privatekey.pem
   ```

The password 123456 is just a temporary stub used only at step 4.

2. Generate the new CSR

   ```
   openssl req -out certreq.csr -key privatekey.pem -new
   ```
3. Generate the new certificate

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -days 18000 -in certreq.csr -signkey privatekey.pem -sha256 -out newcert.pem
   ```
4. Convert key and cert to pkcs12

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out newkeystore.p12 -inkey privatekey.pem -in newcert.pem
   ```

Here you input a temporary password to a PKCS12 keystore (123456).

5. Convert pkcs12 to jks

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore newkeystore.jks -srckeystore newkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias 1 -destalias mykey -destkeypass keypassword
   ```

The keystore password is entered from the keyboard input, and the key alias and password are specified as the command line parameters

I was able to sign the new version of the app with the new keystore. Also, I was able to verify that the keys in the legacy and new keystores are the same.

However, when I tried to update the app signed with the legacy keystore, to the app signed with the new keystore, I first got the message:

```
Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer.
```

After I confirmed the update, I got another message:

```
App not installed as package conflicts with an existing package.
```

Which makes me thinking that **it is not possible to renew the certificate** at all, even if the private keys are the same. So you have to live with your first keystore forever (obviously, it's a bad practice of Android, not to provide any option to renew the developer certificates).

Comment: It is possible, see here for an example https://github.com/Hakky54/java-tutorials/tree/main/instant-server-ssl-reloading

Comment: You are talking about the certificate renewal for the web server. Renewing the web server certificate is certainly possible! Unfortunately this approach does not work for Android application development.

Comment: The OP didn't asked for Android

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that. I think you need to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: I dropped a comment on his question, however he didn't respond. Thanks again for your suggestion, maybe I will just add it anyway as answer